# How do I configure pybuilder?

Tags: python, pybuilder

How can I change the configuration in pybuilder, and how does the configuration in pybuilder work?.

How Do I find out the possible configuration values and their defaults, how do I override or change them per project / per module / on the commmmandline / in settings files? Which are the settings files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1) Locate the initialization method

It is very easy to change the configuration of an exisiting project. Visit the `build.py` file in the root directory of your project and make sure it has this code in it:

```
from pybuilder.core import init
```

and also this (without the dots):

```
@init
def initialize(project):
  ...
```

### 2) Properties example

Plugins are configured using their so called `properties`. There is a list of available plugin properties and their default values available here: http://pybuilder.github.io/documentation/plugins.html If you do not configure something the default value will be used.

There is also a python core plugin, where you can *change default directories*:

http://pybuilder.github.io/documentation/plugins.html#Pythondeployment

This example shows how to change a property of a plugin:

```
project.set_property('unittest_module_glob', '*_unittest')
```

This will set the property `unittest_module_glob` of the `unittest` plugin to the value '*_unittest'.

### 3) Attribute example

There are `attributes` to describe the whole project. For instance to change the version attribute of the project use a line like this one in the `initialize` method:

```
project.version = "0.1.14"
```

### 4) Complete example

Your `.\build.py` could look like this now:

```
from pybuilder.core import use_plugin
from pybuilder.core import init

use_plugin("python.core")
use_plugin("python.unittest")

name = "myfirstproject"
default_task = "publish"

@init
def initialize(project):
  project.version = "0.1.14"
  project.set_property('unittest_module_glob', '*_unittest')
```

### 5) Setting Properties from the command line

Properties can also be set or overridden using command line switches:

```
$ pyb -P unittest_module_glob="*_unittest"
```

### 6) Further reading

Much of all this is explained on the settings page:

http://pybuilder.github.io/documentation/manual.html#Project-specificconfiguration